# Is Android Eclipse Plugin 0.9.9 available anywhere?

Tags: android

Owing to problems with the upgrade to SDK2.3, I now need to back out to an earlier version. Fortunately I had saved a cutdown version of SDK 2.1 which would allow me to continue development. However I upgraded my Eclipse pluigin to 8.0.0, which expects a 2.3 SDK environment. Eclipse now complains that it's now missing the new platform-tools folder when I point the  SDK location to the old 2.1 version and won't allow me to compile.

I need to uninstall the 8.0.0 plugin and replace it with 0.9.9 but there is no option to download it on the can't find it on the developer.android pages.

Comment: I'd have to ask you what problems did you have after the upgrade? And did you run the Eclipse update after the sdk update and check that you had the latest and greatest of everything in the last update?

Comment: I know I had some issues with Eclipse not being able to find the adb but I just re ran all my update checks from eclipse and installed whatever new stuff applied, restarted and everything was gravy after that.

Comment: Just take it as a given that I need to back out. The problems are described in another of my questions tagged android-sdk-2.3. Please just confine this thread to the plugin question

Comment: Oh hey sorry bout that. Just kinda assumed it was a noob question as there seem to be alot of those in the android department. Saw your other questions and yeah... pretty WTF(as in What a Terrible Failure) lol. U get double Bumps from me +2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
Although it's not visible on the site, typing

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-0.9.9.zip

into the browser lets you download the thing. I've finally managed to back out to where I was 2 days ago before '*upgrading*' to SDK2.3